# pandas.to_csv .rstrip not parsing time date correctly. [Pandas] [Python]

Tags: python, csv, datetime, date-formatting, timedelta

Running into a bit of an issue within my .csv file. The default date is formatted in my csv file is `1/12/2011 0:00` within the cells, but when I highlight the cell is shown`1/12/2011 12:00:00 AM`. What I'm trying to do is remove the `0:00 (12:00:00 AM)` from the multiple columns. I'm  trying to use the `.rstrip` call in hopes of correcting this issue. Below is my code and it does compile, but does not remove the `0:00` or **now** the `1/12/2011 12:00:00 AM` default within the .csv file. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this any advice will be welcomed. Thanks.

First Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel ('.xlsx', header=None)
df.to_csv('.csv', header=None, index=False)
dateparse = lambda x: parse(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').rstrip(" 0:00")
df = pd.read_csv('.xlsx', index_col=[5,8,12], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Second Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel ('.xlsx', header=None)
df.to_csv('.csv', header=None, index=False)
dateparse = lambda x: parse(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').rstrip(" 12:00:00 AM")
df = pd.read_csv('.xlsx', index_col=[5,8,12], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Note: As you can see I'm doing a conversion from .xlsx to .csv and figured that correcting the date would be easier once in the .csv format. Also, within the .xlsx file there date columns are not formatted for time so I am not sure as to whats happening.

Comment: why u dont do something like x[0,-5] substring out from datestring?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude it from the format function in the first place and by using `parse` from `dateutil.pareser`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse  
dateparse = lambda x: parse(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

or if you would like to continue to use your approach, then hour format is in 2 digit not 1, so strip `00:00` not `0:00` as follows:

```
dateparse = lambda x: parse(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').rstrip(" 00:00")
```

Comment: Hello, I've found some new information that might be helpful. Also, I tried your approach and it was unsuccessful. Any advice on the newly acquired information above? Thanks. @iDrwish

Comment: I edited the answer to import `parse` from `dateutil`. Can you give me a context on why it didn't work?